# How to rewrite a core python function which is not in a class

Tags: python, python-2.7

We have some previously written code that made changes to some functions in the core library within the python 2.7 distribution. To use our revisions, we now point the python 2.7 library to our own.
I would like to avoid having our own python 2.7 package and move back to the standard distribution while keeping the changes that were made. The changes are not many, with a few functions in misc/utils.py and some class methods.
THe class methods should be fairly easy to fix by extending the classes. However, I am not sure how to do that for the raw functions.

e.g. there is a change in the function misc/utils.py

```
def call(*args, **kwds):
    return subprocess.call(*alist, **kwds)
```

If I want to change this function and have all calls to it switched to my function, is it possible to do it. And what would be the lease invasive way to do it.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding -- You want to change `subprocess.call` to be something else?  Or ... ?

Comment: Can't you just literally overwrite the function? i.e. `class Foo(object): def bar(self): pass` then `def new_bar(self): pass; Foo.bar = new_bar`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not inside a class. It is a bare function and it is used in a variety of classes.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your immediate question - you can [create a patch](https://docs.python.org/devguide/patch.html) and then apply it to the source.  This will keep your modifications separate from the original source.

However, I would **strongly insist** that if you do this, that you run the [test suite](https://docs.python.org/devguide/#quick-start) to make sure your patch doesn't break something else.

If you want all applications to run against your own patched version of Python, this is the most portable way.

If you have this requirement for *your own* apps, you can do any of the following, depending on your requirements:

1. Append a directory with your modifications to the path. You can do this by creating a `sitecustomize.py` file [as detailed in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html). This file will be loaded at each Python invocation and your customizations will be applied. You can then shadow the built-ins with your custom versions.
2. The code that should run with the modifications, you can add your own customizations of built-ins by shadowing them in the source directory. Since the working directory is the first place where Python searches, your customized version of the built-ins will be used. This can then be packaged up so that normal distribute tools can be used, making your modifications portable.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This seems exactly what would work in my case. If I understand correctly, I just need to add only the modified code into my custom directory and then make it shadow the main directory.